# Is there --save option for pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I created requirements.pip file using `pip freeze`

But it has problems it overrides some config such as platform_system.

```
async-timeout==3.0.1; platform_system == "linux"
```

as you could do with `npm install -save`, is there a way to install pip package and add it to dependency list?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Comment: you can use ```pipreqs```. ```pip install pipreqs```  ``` pipreqs /project/path```

Comment: @MohitSolanki i'd like take your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip freeze`

Go to your folder and run `pip freeze`.

`pip freeze > requirements.lock` will put all the requirements you currently have installed into the the file `requirements.lock`

You can read more about this at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/